# Ubuntu 20.04 does not power off on shutdown while screen is off

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop. Sometimes during shutdown the system seems to shutdown and the screen turns off but the machine is still running. I can still see the red bulb on on the power button and the fan is on. I left it like that and the battery went 0%. That happens sometimes. After that I can still turn it on without any problems. However, I don't want battery to drain my battery every time this happens.

```
asus-fx705dt                
    description: Notebook
    product: TUF Gaming FX705DT_FX705DT
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: 
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.2.1 dmi-3.2.1 smp vsyscall32
```

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nvidia 450.